# What is the difference between `*a` and `a[0]`?

Tags: c++

Given a user-defined type `A`, and a pointer `A* a`, what is the difference between `*a` and `a[0]`?

(Though `*(a+0)`/`a[0]` are defined to be equivalent, the same is not the case for `*a`/`a[0]`, where a subtle difference may cause a compilation error in certain circumstances.)

Comment: And, no, lexically appending `++` to the expression and taking incrementability away from `A` does not count.

Comment: "`*a/a[0]`, where a subtle difference may cause a compilation error in certain circumstances" - for example?

Comment: +1, I think it's an interesting riddle. I once coded a begin function like `template<typename T, int N> T *begin(T(&x)[N]) { return &x[0]; }` and didn't notice the subtle useless requirement I induced on `T` by using the array syntax.

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel I'd propose you rewrite your question show the relevant scenarios and compiler errors in your question and give the answer you obviously know. Otherwise I'd agree that 'trolling' isn't the worst term to describe this behavior ...

Comment: are we to take `*a` as an expression, or just as a piece of text? like `b * a` vs `b a[0]`?

Comment: @AndyProwl: As an expression. So yeah not simply lexically. Otherwise the postfix `++` example can get you there.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If `A` is an incomplete type, `*a` works, but `a[0]` does not, [in this example](http://ideone.com/f89mBX):

```
struct A;

void foo(A& r)
{
}

void bar(A* a)
{
    foo(*a);
    foo(a[0]);   // error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct A’
}
```

That's because `a[0]` is equivalent to `*(a+0)`, but you cannot add something to a pointer to an object of incomplete type (not even zero), because pointer arithmetic requires the size to be known.

Comment: Doesn't `sizeof(e)` requires that the type of `e` must be a complete type? Otherwise this would make no sense...

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel You **are** trolling, indeed, even if there's a concise answer.

Comment: @H2CO3: Sorry if you feel that the pursuit of knowledge constitutes "trolling"!

Comment: Answer your own damn questions if you know the answer.

Comment: 3.2/4 says: `A class type T must be complete if [..] the sizeof operator (5.3.3) is applied to an operand of type T`

Comment: Oh... So the C++ standard silently agrees on that references are implemented using pointers...

Comment: @Non-StopTimeTravel The only reasonable explanation of this (dereferencing a pointer to incomplete type, then passing the value by reference) is that byref passing and the dereference operator are, in practice, the inverse of each other, so the two operations cancel out one another, and it's finally only the address of `a` which is passed. If this wasn't the case, then the pointer to incomplete type would actually have to be dereferenced, no?

Comment: @H2CO3: Well, I suppose... That reference binding does not require a complete type perhaps just says more about the semantics of _references_, and not simply because they happen to match those of _pointers_ in this context. They can have the same rules without _being_ pointers.

Comment: @H2CO3: That does not necessarily hold true. A reference is an alias to an object and a pointer is sufficient to create an alias, *here there is an object of type T at address X*. Compare this, for example with a `typedef` with also creates an alias at a different level (to the type). You can create an alias to a type without knowing what the type actually is: `class X; typedef X Y;`. Of course, the natural implementation of the *alias* is a pointer, but that is not required by the standard.

Comment: @DavidRodriguez-dribeas That's what I'm saying :)

Comment: @H2CO3: On the contrary, you are claiming that dereferencing and binding a reference are the inverse of each other. What I am saying is that the standard does not even imply that, it only implies that as long as you don't use it, you can create an alias for an object of unknown type if you know where it lives.